# What determines whether a double displacement reaction will occur?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ionic-compounds, reactivity

In normal displacement reactions, reactivity plays a large role and sometimes the reaction doesn't even happen. So is there anything limiting double displacement reactions? For example $\ce{2KI + Pb(NO3)2 -> 2KNO3 + PbI2}$. If reactivity plays a role in this reaction, why does it occur? Isn't the halogen ion (iodide) more reactive than $\ce{NO3-}$?

(I'm a high school chem student so this may come off as a newbie question, sorry)

Comment: That name (*double displacement*) is nothing more than a name. At university level it is not used to the best of my knowledge. It is *always* the overall balance of reactivity or in your case solubility that matters.

Comment: @Jan could you elaborate on why potassium ion prefers the nitrate ion, if that is the case?

Comment: There is no $\ce{NO3^2-}$, only $\ce{NO3^-}$. Also, there is no such thing as reactivity in general. As for potassium ion, it does not prefer nitrate. Potassium ion does not really "know" that a reaction takes place at all.

Comment: @S.Mo It is not potassium ‘preferring’ nitrate — in fact there are no ‘preferences’ (i.e. choices) involved at all. Rather, $\ce{PbI2}$ has a very low solubility, thus iodide and lead(II) in solution will meet each other and precipitate. Potassium and nitrate are merely spectators.

Comment: @Jan can we predict such equations with other elements using some kind of rule of thumb?

Comment: No.$%comments~$

Comment: @S.Mo generally speaking, the alkali metal ions (Li+, Na+, K+, etc.) and ammonium as well as nitrate and perchlorate will remain in solution. http://www.chem.sc.edu/faculty/morgan/resources/solubility/

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is whether the reaction leads to the formation of a solid (precipitate) or a gas otherwise there is really no reaction

Comment: Generally speaking, that's correct, but it would be great if you could elaborate a little bit or perhaps give some examples.

Answer (score 2):

It's often helpful to use state symbols when dealing with solutions, especially in this case. Let's say you mix $\ce{KI}$ with $\ce{NaNO_3}$. Because the $\ce{KI}$ and $\ce{NaNO_3}$  are soluble and fully dissolved (or assumed to be) in the solutions, before mixing, we write them as $\ce{KI}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ and $\ce{NaNO_3}$ $\ce{(aq)}$. The *aq* stands for aqueous. After you pour them together, the ions in both solutions mix into the larger volume. However, they're still fully dissolved, so no reaction happens. Before, you had $\ce{K^+}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ and $\ce{I^-}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ with $\ce{Na^+}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ and $\ce{NO_3^-}$ $\ce{(aq)}$, and that's exactly what you have afterward. ($\ce{KI (aq)}$ means the same as $\ce{K^+}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ + $\ce{I^-}$ $\ce{(aq)}$, and the same with sodium nitrate).

However, with $\ce{KI}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ and $\ce{PbNO_3}$ $\ce{(aq)}$, they are both initially fully dissolved, but after pouring them together, the $\ce{Pb^{2+}}$$\ce{(aq)}$ ions react with the $\ce{I^-}$ $\ce{(aq)}$ ions and form a yellow solid ($\ce{PbI_2}$) that IS NOT SOLUBLE in water. It comes out of solution as a precipitate. Thus, we write it as $\ce{PbI_2}$ (s). Something actually happened: you had ions that mixed to form a solid.

The equation you have is better written this way:

$\ce{KI (aq) + Pb(NO_3)_2 (aq) -> KNO_3 (aq) + PbI_2 (s)}$.
Notice the solid. If a reaction produces only aqueous products, then nothing happens beyond mixing. If it produces anything that's non-aqeuous (like in this case), THEN there's a chemical reaction.

Comment: Even better is to cancel the spectator ions, i.e., potassium ion and nitrate ion.