# How does a double displacement reaction work?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

When a double displacement reaction occurs with compound AB and CD, what determines that B and C are going to bond instead of A and C?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines whether a double displacement reaction will occur?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41495/what-determines-whether-a-double-displacement-reaction-will-occur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double displacement reactions involve ionic compounds, i.e. salts formed from positive cations and negative anions. Consider the following setup,
$$\ce{\color{blue}{A^{+}}\color{red}{B^{-}} + \color{blue}{C^{+}}\color{red}{D^{-}} -> \color{blue}{A^{+}}\color{red}{D^{-}} + \color{blue}{C^{+}}\color{red}{B^{-}}}$$
where the cations are indicated in blue and anions in red (and all charges are $\pm 1$ to reflect your question). All salts are comprised of cations and anions, hence $\ce{\color{blue}{AC}}$ wouldn't form since both are cations. $\ce{\color{blue}{C}\color{red}{B}}$ would form instead.